# SPF results are different for the same email in two Google accounts, one personal and the other corporate

Tags: email, spf

Currently, I am sending the same message to two recipients. One of them is a personal Gmail account. The other, is a corporative Gmail account.

The thing is that the accounts have different result for my SPF:

Personal account:

> Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@mydomain.com designates
>   108.xxx.xxx.243 as permitted sender) client-ip=108.xxx.xxx.243;

Corporative account:

> Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning
>   info@mydomain.com does not designate 54.xxx.xxx.252 as permitted
>   sender) client-ip=54.xxx.xxx.252;

The email is sent by the same tool, with the same configurations and methods:

> Received: from ec2-54-74-148-252.eu-west-1.xxx.xxx.com
>   ([54.xxx.xxx.252]:56084
>   helo=f93d48d0-1563-4368-8dbd-bcb439a264f6.xxx.xxx.com) by
>   liv.xxx.com with esmtpsa
>   (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256) (Exim 4.92) (envelope-from
>   ) id 1iNekZ-0002IM-32 for
>   testing@xxx.com; Thu, 24 Oct 2019 12:10:07 -0300

This is identical in both emails, but they have differente SPF results.

Do you have any idea about this?

Thank you very much.

**Update**

Both emails were sent from the same server and domain

**Update**

The emails were sent from a platform whose infrastructure is in Amazon. The Amazon server connects to a email server and this email server finally sent the email.

The thing is, my personal email is checking the SPF against the IP of my email server.

But, the corporate email is checking the SPF against the Amazon IP

Comment: SPF isn't coming from your server, it is a record associated with the DNS. If the emails were sent from different domains they would have different SPF records. Also if you just update it, or were in the processes of updating you SPF record it could cause this issue.

Comment: @nzajt The emails were sent both from the same domain, that is the most strange thing...

Comment: Are you sure you have the same "from" footprint for the first email ? I would be surprise to see a Received:from [54.*] and a spf-client-ip = 108.* in the same mail header

Comment: @iguypouf Yes, i double checked this. Also used https://www.diffchecker.com/ to be sure about that :) they were received from the same domain and IP.

Comment: @iguypouf The emails were sent from a platform whose infrastructure is in Amazon. The Amazon server connects to a email server and this email server finally sent the email.

The thing is, my personal email is checking the SPF against the IP of my email server.

But, the corporate email is checking the SPF against the Amazon IP

Comment: Does your corporate email server enforces a TLS encryption for emails ?

Comment: @iguypouf yes, we are using enforced TLS

Comment: So I suspect that your sender email server has not TLS enabled, so the NSLookup under TLS protocol points to Amazon Infra.